# Elevate permission to run exe in java

Tags: java

I need to run a bat file using a java code. I did that in the following way

```
Process process =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start  D:\\Work\\BOSync\\TestFoxPro\\ATSFill.bat");
int exitVal = process.waitFor();
```

Problem is I can run the bat but the task of the bat not happened. I run the bat to load data from CSV file to oracle database using `sqlldr`. When I double click on the bat it works fine.
I think the problem is JVM doesn't has enough permission to run the bat. Is there a way to elevate the permission in java?

Comment: Did you get some exception? If so show its trace. Does the .bat start? Add something like `time /T > atsfill.log` to your .bat and look if `atsfill.log` is created.

Comment: This sounds like a path issue to me. Try using absolute paths to the binary that you are using in your bat file and set other environment variables that your script need.

Comment: Hey guys finally i Sort it out. The problem was in my bat file. It was like that previously.                                           cd \C:\oracle\ora92\bin
sqlldr GAMINI/gamini C:\AOTITS\CLSTMAS.ctl log=C:\AOTITS\CLSTMAS.log.  Then I remove the path of oracle bin and add it to system path. Then it works fine. Thanks for your help

Comment: Also I need to suppressed the CMD window which is popup in the java code. do you guys know how to do that.

Comment: You can add this as answer and accept it. Then this question will not be listed as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys finally i Sort it out. The problem was in my bat file. It was like that previously. cd \C:\oracle\ora92\bin sqlldr GAMINI/gamini C:\AOTITS\CLSTMAS.ctl log=C:\AOTITS\CLSTMAS.log. Then I remove the path of oracle bin and add it to system path. Then it works fine. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a path issue to me. Try using absolute paths to the binary that you are using in your bat file and set other environment variables that your script need.

As for the cmd window popping up - try just calling the bat file directly and not use the cmd /c command.